# Unable to get cookie after deploying backend to vercel

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cookies, vercel

I deployed my backend and frontend to vercel, but couldn't fetch cookies after deployment. Here is my code of setting the cookies. I am receiving it in the application part of browser as well

````
userRouter.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
  console.log(user);
  const hashed_password = user?.password;
  bcrypt.compare(password, hashed_password, async function (err, result) {
    if (result) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, "secretkey");
      console.log(token);
      res.cookie("jwttoken", token, {
        httpOnly: false,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: true,
      });

      res.send({ msg: "login successful" });
    } else {
      res.send("login failed");
    }
  });
});```

I am receiving the cookie in the browser
![I am getting my cookie in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ssac.png)

I have tried everything but couldn't fetch the cookie.
````